# I can't run the program in the terminal

Tags: python, windows, pycharm, console

Error Message:

```
C:\Users\Marija\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe: can't open file 'C:/Users/Marija/PycharmProjects/Hello World/main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Process finished with exit code 2
```

Comment: The error is there. File is not found.

Comment: Use ls or dir to list the contents of the present working directory then run the program.

Comment: File is not found....Windows cmd?

Answer (score 1):

With my experience in using Python on Windows, I suppose your problem is a result of coping directory link from File Explorer - you have to change every slash (`/`) to backslash (`\`).
I think it's the solution, because in your Error Message you've got two directories with different slashes - system's directory to python.exe (rather correct) with backslashes and yours with slashes.

If it isn't a point, use command `dir` (Windows) or `ls` (unix) to check, if your file is in its place. To change your location, use `cd`.

Next time, remember it'd have been way easier to help you, if you had showed us what you had inserted into terminal. The more information, the better.

Comment: Yep, Windows is backslashes and the error shows an attempted running of path w forward slashes

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to be sure about where the file you want to run is physically kept in your system.

1. Just right click over the module/file name which you want to run.
2. Choose the option of Show in system explorer from there and copy the path from there.
3. In the terminal just change the location to be the copied location and then run the file by giving the name of the file.